# sql server 2008 , suspend process

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

net application that has about 50 - 70 users concurrent.
it works for some months, but from 3 days ago we have many time out on sql server.
heaviest query's times is about 5 Sec ( when single user works)
I didnt change any query / app and can't understand why I face this problem.
I have 2 servers ( one for IIS and another for DB) the only change is public IP address of IIS server ( and network admin told me they didnt change any things on local area network)

1- how can I manage suspend process? is there any setting that can restart service or kill suspend process?

### 2- how can I find which Items make these problems?

we use : windows server 2003 , IIS 6 , SQL server 2008 , asp.net 3.5
Thanks

update :
 all queries which uses paging will be suspended on server

Comment: What are the top 10 wait types in `sys.dm_os_wait_stats`?

Comment: MISCELLANEOUS
LCK_M_SCH_S
LCK_M_SCH_M
LCK_M_S
LCK_M_U
LCK_M_X
LCK_M_IS
LCK_M_IU
LCK_M_IX
LCK_M_SIU

Comment: That looks like a blocking problem then. They are all waits on locks rather than (say) IO. This should help you troubleshoot it http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2007/02/21/sql-server-2005-performance-statistics-script.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) There only one way to manage suspended process - to Kill it. 
Run `sp_who2` to get `SPID` with Suspended status you want to kill
Than run command `Kill <SPID>`

2) You need to properly test your app to find where is problem. Try to automate this process to make multiple connections at the same time. Also use SQL profiler to see the queries which coming to your SQL Server, this way you may trace the query which becoming suspended, than you may take this query and run it in the query window as a result you may see more details whats really happened.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the app works fine before this sunday. we dont have any change on it, we use paging for all queries by large amount of result which now make time out on server

Comment: @Ashian May be any database changes was taking place? Any new columns where added or deleted etc..?

Comment: I Rollback all changes ( I add 2 columns to a view ), also re index all index.